# How to post data from react front to laravel background

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel-5, react-redux

I have a react component, and in it's state, i got some data that need to save in db by php Laravel, how can i do this?
Should I do this in `reducer`?
1. use `Ajax` 
2. use form 
I don't sure if there is a way to use form post data, if it's ok
Please give me a demo. I'm new to react, and searched no result, thanks!

Comment: Please provide some sample code of what you have tried so far. Check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch API.

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

OR
Jquery Ajax API.

```
$.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

Posting Data in React or any other frame work is based on what you choose.
Here for Example:
The Fetch API has built in methods for different datatypes.
For just regular text/html you'd use the text() method, which returns a promise as well, and chain it with another then call.

Hope this helps you. Please feel free to ask if not cleared with your doubt